# Describe an arm without a forearm

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Usually an arm looks like this:

Shoulder -- upper arm -- elbow -- forearm -- wrist -- hand.

But suppose, because of either chemical poisoning or radiation *in utero*, Kevin was born without a left forearm. Then his elbow and wrist would be fused into some hybrid structure joint, and the left arm would look like this:

Shoulder -- upper arm -- elbow/wrist -- hand.

Suppose this had already been described in detail. Then Kevin leaves the narrative for a few hundred pages, and when he comes back I want to remind the readers which character he is. In particular I want to remind them of the layout of his left arm because it is to become plot relevant. So I want to insert a marker back to the original description without repeating it.

Since the hundred pages of text only spans a week or so in story (let's make it a working week with the narrator only seeing Kevin on weekends), the narrator certainly doesn't need to be reminded who Kevin is. So I decide to slip in something like. . .

"Kevin cycled at a restrained pace. He knew his _______ arm would prevent him from making quick turns in an emergency."

I think that's a fairly subtle way to remind the readers. But what should go in the blank space? Feel free to muck around with the format as you wish. What I really want is just a summary of the earlier description.

Comment: Hey, is this part of a Psych project to identify uses of descriptions with "negative connotations"?

Comment: Slang (and a bit pejorative) is "gimpy".  "Deformed" is a bit less pejorative, but still, to a degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I didn't mind bad puns, I'd call it 'foreshortened':

> having the length reduced, curtailed or abridged.

(Definition from [*The Free Dictionary*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/foreshortened), *American Heritage* sense 2, paraphrased to suit the context.)

'Foreshortened' might be best if what is desired is a genteel tone, edging on discreet but with a possible slightly humorous doubletake on 'foreshortened by a forearm'. I mention the potential humor just so you're forewarned, because "forewarned is forearmed".

However, I'm *stumped* by the question:

> reduced to a stump.

(Definition from [*The Free Dictionary*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stumped), *American Heritage*, transitive verb sense 1, paraphrased to suit the context.)

Using 'stumped' might fit with a less genteel, more direct or colloquial tone. Nothing nuanced about *stumped*.

Answer (score 5):

I'd call it *his **stunted** arm*...

[**stunt**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stunt) *- prevent from growing or developing properly* (oxforddictionaries)

---

Here's a typical example usage from [The New Yorker (1980)...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22against%20his%20stunted%20leg.%20His%22)

> *My mother took hold of his ankle, whitening her knuckles against his **stunted leg**. His left leg was short. It made every step a lunge.*

Answer (score 2):

One could also call it a *malformed* or *deformed* arm.  The former would emphasize that it had not developed properly, the latter that it had suffered some injury or environmental insult.